# SQL Query to find if most recent records are all of the same type

Tags: mysql

I have a `transaction` table with a schema like

```
id | order_id | response | amount
1  | 2        |'payment' | 1000
2  | 5        |'declined'| 0
3  | 5        |'declined'| 0
4  | 5        |'payment' | 500
5  | 5        |'declined'| 0
6  | 11       |'declined'| 0
7  | 11       |'declined'| 0
9  | 11       |'declined'| 0
```

What I wand to do is find all orders, where the three most recent transactions for that order are 'declined'.  Assume the higher the id, the more recent the transaction (or you can assume there is a created_at column).

In the above case, the only order_id that should be returned is `11` because while order_id `5` has 3 declined transactions, the most recent 3 transaction are `D P D`

Is there a clean way to do this with pure sql that runs in a reasonable about of time (assuming ~50M rows).

Comment: The records in your table don't appear to have their timestamp recorded anywhere... how do you propose one determine which are the "most recent"?

Comment: ...and add more sample data. When developing a query you want to be sure, that it covers all cases, right? So your sample data should at least have data that would be returned by a correct query.

Comment: I edited the question so you can assume there is a created_at column or the id column is monotonically increasing with time.  It shouldn't make much difference for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the higher id the more recent:

```
SELECT t0.order_id 
FROM transaction t0 
JOIN transaction t1 ON
   ((t1.response=t0.response) AND (t1.order_id=t0.order_id) AND 
   t1.id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM transaction WHERE id<t0.id and t0.order_id=order_id)) 
JOIN transaction t2 ON 
   ((t2.response=t0.response) AND (t2.order_id=t0.order_id) AND 
   t2.id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM transaction WHERE id<t1.id AND t0.order_id=order_id)) 
WHERE t0.response='declined' AND 
   t0.id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM transaction WHERE order_id=t0.order_id);
```

Comment: This works well and runs instantly.  The only downside is it is not very flexible, as you have to write a new query if you want to search for 4 declines.

Comment: You are right. But it can be easily extended: ... JOIN transaction t3 ON 
   ((t3.response=t0.response) AND (t3.order_id=t0.order_id) AND 
   t3.id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM transaction WHERE id<t2.id AND t0.order_id=order_id) ...

Answer (score 1):

Not a fast solution at all, but it should give you what you want (I assume recent transaction is transaction with higher value of `id` column) :

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT  *,
     (
        SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM `transaction` a WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id AND
        a.id >= b.id 
     )as num
    FROM `transaction`b
    ) a WHERE num =3
    AND NOT EXISTS
      (
       SELECT NULL FROM `transaction` b where response<>'declined' 
       and b.order_id = a.order_id and b.id >=a.id
      )
```

Comment: I confirmed this gives correct results.  The problem is that it is a bit slow.   it takes a few minutes, to return about 50 rows.

Comment: Just as a reference, this query starts by assigning the recency to every transaction, then limits to the third most recent transactions.  The where clause then verifies that all transactions newer or equal than the third most recent transaction is 'declined'.  This is a clever solution where the "3" parameter is flexible, and it is easy to modify.  Unfortunately, it is a bit slow, but a very clever an interesting technique.  Thanks for taking the time to answer, I definitely learned something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.order_id
           FROM 
              ( SELECT x.*
                     , COUNT(*) rank 
                  FROM my_table x 
                  JOIN my_table y 
                    ON y.order_id = x.order_id 
                   AND y.id >= x.id 
                 GROUP 
                    BY id HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
              ) a
           LEFT
           JOIN
              ( SELECT x.*
                     , COUNT(*) rank 
                  FROM my_table x 
                  JOIN my_table y 
                    ON y.order_id = x.order_id 
                   AND y.id >= x.id 
                 GROUP 
                    BY id HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
              ) b
             ON b.order_id = a.order_id
            AND b.response <> 'declined'
          WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Fiddle of same: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/386aa3/1

Just a thought... does this work (untested)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.order_id
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.order_id = x.order_id
   AND y.id >= x.id
 GROUP
    BY x.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 
   AND COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN y.response = 'declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Comment: This is so slow I am not sure I will be able to verify that it is correct.

Comment: Yeah - it IS likely to be slow. Sorry about that - also it's not quite sure what to do when there are less than 3 results, but all of which have been declined.

Comment: Note that this solution would benefit slightly from a composite index on (order_id,response) - but it still doesn't know what to do when there are fewer than 3 results (because you haven't said)